# Wordpress 301 Redirect not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am moving from a Wordpress site to a shopify site with a change of URL.

I have used the 301 Redirects plugin to send all site traffic from:

https://power-focus.co.uk    >     https://www.brainpowernootropics.com.

Except what I ended up with when I visit the first site expecting to get redirected is the first URL and the second URL together and no redirection.

No redirect happened? It just added the second URL on to the end of the first. (I dont know how to access the htaccess file as I dont have the server login details and don't know how to get them)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The above links are working fine. the power-focus url is redirecting to the new one. However, you should redirect using wild card, meaning `https://power-focus.co.uk/any-page` must redirect to `https://www.brainpowernootropics.com/any-page`

Comment: Thanks Junaid!

Ahh okay, I wasnt sure what the wildcard option reffered to!

I have now used Godaddy directly to create the 301.

Answer (score 0):

The above links are working fine. The power-focus url is redirecting to the new one.

However, you should redirect using wild card, meaning

```
https://power-focus.co.uk/any-page
```

must redirect to

```
https://www.brainpowernootropics.com/any-page
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Junaid,

Thanks, im using Godaddy to do the 301, what way do you recommend adding the wildcard?

Comment: @Ash Check this [article](https://pk.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120) on GoDaddy.